# Comparing arrays and creating new one if it does not contain values

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare a `$badArray` against an array `$companyArray` and create a new array called `$goodArray`. If the `$companyArray` contains a matching `Company_Name` from `$badArray` then do NOT add this to `$goodArray`. I have 1197 values in `$badArray` and 1410 in `$companyArray`. I am comparing the arrays using two `foreach` loops but for some reason the `$goodArray` does not generate properly it should in the end contain 213 entries but only contains the very last entry from the `$companyArray` that was not bad. I hope this makes sense can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and if there is a better way to sift through the two arrays?

```
public function SortGoodFromBad($badArray, $companyArray) {
    $goodArray = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($companyArray as $row => $value) {
        foreach($badArray as $companyName => $companyRow) {
            if($companyName !== $value['Company_Name']) {
                $goodArray = array('Company Name'.$i => $value['Company_Name']);
                $i++;
            } else {

            }
        }
    }

    echo "<PRE>";
    print_r($goodArray);
    echo "</PRE>";
}
```

Comment: You should look into `array_diff` - it returns the difference between two arrays, so you could use it like `$goodArray = array_diff($companyArray, $badArray)` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look up http://php.net/in_array and http://php.net/Array. As for your example, if I understood right:

```
function SortGoodFromBad($badArray,$companyArray) {
  $goodArray = Array();
  foreach ($companyArray as $row=>$value) {
    if (!isset($badArray[$value])) $goodArray[] = $value;
  }
}
```

I used variables as you used them. Could you output first few rows of print_r($badArray) and first few rows of print_r($companyArray), if you see any problems.

Comment: `$goodArray` is a multidimensional array I need to loop through and match the `Company_Name`. `$badArray` is just a normal array that contains the company names.

Comment: I had to add `['Company_Name']` to the `$value` in the `foreach` and yes it worked but for some reason it is one entry short? there should be 213 entries in the `$goodArray` but there is only 211 with the 0 index that makes 212.

Comment: It loops through whole $companyArray, so there is no mistake there. Maybe it is not 213?

Answer (score 1):

a little late but might be little fast . you may give it a try

```
function arrayDiff($arrayFrom, $arrayAgainst){
    $arrayAgainst = array_flip($arrayAgainst);

    foreach ($arrayFrom as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($arrayAgainst[$value])) {
            unset($arrayFrom[$key]);
        }
    }  
    return $arrayFrom;
}
// example
$badarr=array('a','b','c'); 
$comanyarr=array('a'=>1,'d'=>2,'e'=>3,'s'=>4,'c'=>5);

print_r(arrayDiff($comanyarr,$badarr)); //Array ( [a] => 1 [d] => 2 [e] => 3 [s] => 4 [c] => 5 )
```